# How to align parameters in android itext?

Tags: java, android, pdf-generation, itext, text-alignment

I generate this PDF file:

[PDF File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmAYf.png)

But i don't know why alignment the quantities, something like that:

[I'd like it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8QUz.png)

That's my code:

```
 private static boolean addContent(Document document, CreditoIndividual socioObjeto) throws DocumentException {
    Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Ticket", subFont);
    subPara.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    addEmptyLine(subPara, socioObjeto);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    addEmptyLine(paragraph, socioObjeto);
    document.add(subPara);
    return (true);
}

private static boolean addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, CreditoIndividual socioObjeto) {
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy / HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Fecha: " + date, catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Semana: " + socioObjeto.getSemana(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Socio: " + socioObjeto.getNombre(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Monto Principal: $" + socioObjeto.getPago_principal_cap(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Monto Principal" + "\n" + "Vencido: $" + socioObjeto.getPago_vencido_cap(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Monto Oportuno: $" + socioObjeto.getPago_oportuno_cap(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Monto Oportuno Vencido: $" + socioObjeto.getPago_vencido_oportuno_cap(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Monto Mora Principal: $" + socioObjeto.getMora_principal_cap(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Monto Mora Oportuno: $" + socioObjeto.getMora_secundario_cap(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Monto Aportación: $" + socioObjeto.getAportacion_cap(), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Total Pagado: $" + (socioObjeto.getPago_principal_cap() + socioObjeto.getPago_vencido_cap()
            + socioObjeto.getMora_principal_cap() + socioObjeto.getPago_oportuno_cap() + socioObjeto.getPago_vencido_oportuno_cap()
            + socioObjeto.getMora_secundario_cap() + socioObjeto.getAportacion_cap()), catFont));
    paragraph.add(new Paragraph("Monto de Oportunos"+ "\n" + "Solicitados: $" + socioObjeto.getMonto_prestamo_oportuno_cap(), catFont));
    return (true);
}
```

Thanks for reading me.

Comment: You seem to want to render some kind of table. How about using itext table classes (`PdfPTable` etc.)?

Comment: You better go with these examples..http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/101-very-simple-table